# How do I manipulate the values to a pointer to a struct

Tags: c, pointers, struct

It's a function that makes events based off the time values the user enters, it then converts the value to Unix Epoch using `mktime` and stores them to a file. I've tested and found that everything else works well until we reach the section where the user enters the values seems like I'm not using the pointer `event` to the `struct tm` well, so I need help in doing it right.

```
int EventCreator(){
      FILE *fptr = fopen("Events_Calendar.txt", "a+");
      struct tm *event;
      printf("Enter the values of the hour minute day month year in digits and this specific format meaning using spaces to seperate them");
      printf("\n hr min day mon yr\n>");
      scanf("%d %d %d %d %d", event->tm_hour, event->tm_min, event->tm_mday, event->tm_mon, event->tm_year);
      time_t NineteenEvent = mktime(event);
      printf("%ld", NineteenEvent);
      fprintf(fptr, "%ld\n", NineteenEvent);
      fclose(fptr); 
      }
```

Comment: Firstly, `event` is an uninitialised pointer so dereferencing it results in undefined behaviour. Secondly, `scanf` requires pointers but you are giving it `int` variables. Try: `struct tm event; scanf("%d %d %d %d %d", &event.tm_hour, &event.tm_min, &event.tm_mday, &event.tm_mon, &event.tm_year);` If that doesn't solve the problem then please tell us what error or incorrect behaviour you are observing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have declared a pointer to a `struct tm` but you haven't allocated memory for a `struct tm`. I suggest that you make `event` an automatic variable instead.

Example:

```c
void EventCreator() { // make the function `void` since you do not return anything
    FILE *fptr = fopen("Events_Calendar.txt", "a+");
    if (fptr) {                             // check that opening the file succeeds

        // `event` is now not a pointer and set `tm_isdst` to a negative value
        // to make `mktime` guess if DST is in effect:
        struct tm event = {.tm_isdst = -1};

        printf(
            "Enter the values of the hour minute day month year in digits and "
            "this specific format meaning using spaces to seperate them\n"
            "hr min day mon yr\n>");

        // %d requires an `int*` but you've supplied it with `int`.
        // (also, check that scanf succeeds)
        if (scanf("%d %d %d %d %d", &event.tm_hour, &event.tm_min,
                  &event.tm_mday, &event.tm_mon, &event.tm_year) == 5) {

            event.tm_year -= 1900; // years since 1900
            --event.tm_mon;        // 0-11
            time_t NineteenEvent = mktime(&event); // take its address here
            printf("%ld", NineteenEvent);
            fprintf(fptr, "%ld\n", NineteenEvent);
            fclose(fptr);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks making `event` a variable fixed the problem with giving it values but now when I call `mktime()` to change the time into Epoch it doesn't work since it only accepts struct pointers even when I use `&event` which I'm assuming is kind of like a pointer it still doesn't work, it's returning -1 for some reason.

Comment: @uZuMaKioBaRuTo You're welcome. Strange, it works fine for me. What input do you give it? Did you also make the offset calculation on the year and month and initialize `event` like I showed?